# Sonarqube SQLServer error

Tags: sql-server, sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

I have this error each time I check "remember me" on authentication.
What could be the problem ?
Thank you

Dom

```
2016.04.12 18:49:27 ERROR web[o.s.s.ui.JRubyFacade] Fail to render: http://cerbere:9001/sessions/login
ActiveRecord::JDBCError: La conversion d'un type de donn?es varchar en type de donn?es datetime a cr?? une valeur hors limites.: UPDATE [users] SET [remember_token_expires_at] = '2016-04-26 16:49:26', [remember_token] = N'4fa37dcb929dce851bb153cebc204bc300518d14', [updated_at] = 1460479767007 WHERE [id] = N'2'
/opt/sonar/sonarqube-5.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:227:in `log'
/opt/sonar/sonarqube-5.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:212:in `log'
/opt/sonar/sonarqube-5.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.1.3/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/adapter.rb:183:in `execute'
/opt/sonar/sonarqube-5.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.1.3/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/adapter.rb:199:in `jdbc_update'
/opt/sonar/sonarqube-5.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:26:in `update_with_query_dirty'
/opt/sonar/sonarqube-5.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/base.rb:2946:in `update'
/opt/sonar/sonarqube-5.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/locking/optimistic.rb:81:in `update_with_lock'
/opt/sonar/sonarqube-5.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/dirty.rb:146:in `update_with_dirty'
/opt/sonar/sonarqube-5.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:64:in `update_with_timestamps'
/opt/sonar/sonarqube-5.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:282:in `update_with_callbacks'
```

Comment: What's your version?

Comment: What's the type of the MySQL columns USERS.REMEMBER_TOKEN_EXPIRES_AT and USERS.UPDATED_AT ? Moreover what's the version of MySQL ?

Comment: I managed to fix this. My version of sonar is 5.4.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was on soanrqube 5.4. It was due to my sqlserver user language that was not english.
I read again sonarqube installation documentation, and it's not very clear what to do for MS SQLServer.